# Bluetooth iOS Pairing

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth

I have a fitness app that is already in the app store and now I want to implement a bluetooth device that users can purchase if they wish. This is my first time dealing with bluetooth and after reading  "Core Bluetooth Programming Guide", I have the following questions.

My app contains information that my bluetooth device requires simply to display the data. If I'm not mistaken, this makes the app the "Peripheral" because it has the data. The bluetooth device wants the data from the app so that makes the bluetooth device the "Central". Am I correct about this?

Finally, here is where I get confused. The bluetooth device has a button that I want when pressed to trigger the app to get the app to send new values to the bluetooth device. Is this possible? The reason I ask because in this scenario, would this now mean that the bluetooth device is the peripheral and the app is the central? If yes, will I have to break the current connection between the two in order to switch their roles (manager, and peripheral)?

Thank you in advance, really appreciate it!

Ted

Comment: First of all: Is it a Bluetooth Low Energy device or a "Classical" Bluetooth device? Because, in the first option, you'll have to use `CoreBluetooth.framework` and in the second one `ExternalAccessory.framework`, and that's 2 ways of thinking/implementation.

Comment: @Larme My apologies for not stating, its Low energy. I am using CoreBluetoooth already. Can you please answer my question in the final paragraph if possible? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have control over coding the app and coding the device, you can make it work either way around (Assuming the device is to be used specifically with your app and nothing else).

Both central and peripheral have methods to read and write data from/to the peripheral.

Without more information on the data and how often it's updated, it's difficult to suggest the best way to do it.

You say your device will have a button that will tell the app to send data over to it, well the app won't need to send anything it simply keeps values up to date then your button would tell your device to read the latest value.

Or (Again without knowing the purpose this may not suit) you do away with the button completely and your device subscribes to a characteristic in the app and is notified every time the value is changed by the app.

Comment: Yes, just because a device is operating in a peripheral role doesn't mean it can't be sent data. You can write to an attribute just as you can read from it. I've done bidirectional serial communication with a Bluetooth LE RS-232 adapter, for example.

Comment: @Brad Larson thank you for elaborating Brad. And thank you Darren for a clear explanation. Will accept!